# What is the difference between sampler2Drect and sampler2d?

Tags: glsl, vulkan

as the glsl spec said

```
gvec4 texture(  gsampler2D sampler,
    vec2 P,
    [float bias]);
gvec4 texture(  gsampler2DRect sampler,
    vec2 P);
```

and i tested this two condition in vulkan. I bind the same image data and give the same coordinate. The results are same.
So what is the difference between them. Can i construct the condition which sampler2D and sampler2DRect have different result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most important difference between a 2D texture and a rectangle texture is that 2D textures actually work in Vulkan while rectangle textures *don't*.

[Rectangle textures](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Rectangle_Texture) are an old vestige of OpenGL, one that Vulkan does not use. For OpenGL, a rectangle texture is a special texture type (distinct from a 2D texture) that has exactly one mipmap and whose texture coordinates are not normalized, but you can still have filtering. The unnormalized texture coordinates are a particular feature of rectangle textures.

In Vulkan and SPIR-V, whether texture coordinates are normalized or not is a part of the *sampler*, not of the texture type. So you can get the same effect of a rectangle texture by setting the appropriate parameter in the sampler and using `textureLod` in your GLSL shader (and `sampler2D` as the sampler type). You need to use `textureLod` because `texture` relies on implicit LOD computations, which Vulkan doesn't allow on unnormalized coordinates.